# Filling the viewport after applying rotation transform in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I'm using the Bing Maps Control for silverlight. Currently the Map's width and height is set to match the width and height of container grid.

After applying a rotatetransform to change the angle of the map, the map no longer stretches to fill the grid layer.

Other than resizing the map such that the area is larger than visible region of the grid control, is there a way to have the map auto stretch so that the visible region of the grid is completely filled with the map?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve. What do you mean by '"repeat/fill" over the "background?"'? And what background is showing after the rotation is applied?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity, I've updated the question in the hopes of making it more clear.